# How to understand what Columns Have Changed in Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I am using merge replication in SQL 2012. Some of my merge articles use column level tracking.

I am trying to understand how to use the 'lineage', and 'colv1' fields in the MSmerge_contents table to work out which columns have changed in a particular row in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sp_showlineage and sp_showcolv to inspect the lineage and columns that have been changed.  The sp_showcolv results contain a column, **colidx**, which is the index of the column(s) that were changed for a given version of the row.

If you need to take a more proactive approach, you can setup an auditing scheme.  I've provided an example of how to setup an auditing scheme on my blog:  http://www.sqlrepl.com/sql-server/auditing-changes-in-merge-replication/

Comment: Auditing scheme. Yeah that might be necessary too. Very handy.